# uninitializedpropertyaccessexception: lateinit property gson error in azure sdk

Tags: android, azure, kotlin

I've implemented the Azure database in my app. In Android orio and pie version devices when an app goes in the background for a while, App is crashing when back to the app. I've checked the master key and account name but it's not null still an app is crashing.

I've attached the screenshot of the crash log.[image: Crashing Log]

Updated: I've added sdk module to my project and getting the Runtime exception while app come after long time. Here is the snap.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We use Gson library as a singleton design pattern, which is eventually a static reference and got killed when you go to background. Also share your code where you are initializing gson.

Comment: Error showing in this file. 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-android/blob/master/azuredata/src/main/java/com/azure/data/util/json/GsonConfig.kt 
There is **lateinit var gson** Gson which is not initialized and in application class initialized azure data with a master key and account name.

Comment: We tried with module sdk and initialize the gson variable but still getting runtime exception. I've edited the question.